# Placeholder image showing on the front end. Magento 1.9 - Happy to pay to be fixed

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, cache, placeholder

I have had a Magento 1.9.1 site since 2015. All has worked fine. I moved hosting companies and now a year later when I have gone to upload more products the images do not appear on the front end. All that is shown on the front end is a placeholder image. The image looks fine in the backend.

I have done the following to resolve; none of which has worked.

1. Flushed all the cache.
2. Disabled cache management.
3. Re-indexed all the files under index management
4. Installed a no flash uploader that allows me to add images in the back end and they appear, because flash is no longer supported in browsers.
5. Imported new products via csv import and the images appear in the back end.
6. Set the scope under attributes for image, small image and thumbnail from store view to global.
7. Checked the Low PHP Memory Limit, and it’s set to 512.
8. Ensured that a category is assigned to the product.
9. Set the correct websites to the product.
10. Changed the attributes/permissions of the ‘media’ folder from 755 to 777. I have done this for all the folders and images within media.
11. Checked that the folder owner is the same user as the web server user.

None of the above has worked. All that is shown is a placeholder image.

The one thing which I have noticed is that when I search in cpanel for an older image it will show lots of the same image in folders within media/catalog. These are obviously cached images created at the time of import. However when I import new images these cache images are not being created.

Can any-one help?

Happy to pay for some-one to fix it if they have the knowledge, as I have done all I can think of/find.